# libmodbus: modbus_mapping_new() not working on WSL

Tags: python, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, libmodbus

I'm using libmodbus to setup a modbus slave. The app is setting a slave using the command

```
modbus_mapping_new(500, 500, 500, 500)
```

When I run it on my windows PC I get this output:

```
Slave(0) - Slave Mapping Content:
Slave(0) - nb_bits 500
Slave(0) - nb_input_bits 500
Slave(0) - nb_registers 500
Slave(0) - nb_input_registers 500
```

When I run it on WSL I get this output:

```
Slave(0) - Slave Mapping Content:
Slave(0) - nb_bits 500
Slave(0) - nb_input_bits 0
Slave(0) - nb_registers 0
Slave(0) - nb_input_registers 500
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this initialization issue? The library is the same but one is a `.dll` and the other is a `.so`

Comment: I'm not familiar with modbus, but I see it has two modes - Serial and TCP/IP.  Which are you using?  Also, WSL1 or WSL2?